# CentOS7 CloudFlare DNS

Tags: centos, rhel, dns, resolv.conf

I'm trying to make my server use CloudFlare public DNS (`1.1.1.1`, `1.0.0.1`).

When I edit `/etc/resolv.conf` I see:

```
; generated by /usr/sbin/dhclient-script
nameserver 10.10.10.10
```

When I update it to this, it gets erased on reboot:

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.0.0.1
```

From [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/638045) it makes it sound simple by adding executable to `dhclient-enter-hooks.d` except I don't have that directory.

When I tried to create it I couldn't edit files in it, after looking at `ls` for awhile it seems it has a `.` which makes it have a policy?

What would be the easiest means of doing this? I have an outgoing MTA that generates many external lookups which is why I wanted to do this. I tried installing `unbound` and it was a disaster, so I went this route as it seemed simple... on the surface.

I'm not sure if this matters, but my server also has 5 IPs assigned to it for `ifcfg-eth0`, `ifcfg-eth0:0`, `ifcfg-eth0:1`, etc

Thanks

Comment: Would manually disabling updates to `resolv.conf` work for you? https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=59796

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not sure if that's good or bad. Considering resolv.conf has literally only a single line in it (that I want to change), I imagine its OK?